# Find random element with ace.js

Tags: javascript, regex, ace-editor

How is it possible to find some random element in some code pasted into ace.js editor?
Example:

```
editor.find("<[a-z]+>",{regExp:true});
```

On a XML-Code like this, the statement will only find the first element

```
<root>
   <element1></element1>
   <element2></element2>
   <element3></element3>
</root>
```

How is it possible to find a random element? e.g. element1, 2 or 3...

BTW: ace.js is providing a way to find all of these elements.

Thank you!

Comment: Why would you want to select a random string?

Comment: @freakish The code doesn´t matter. You can handle this XML-Code as a regular string.

Comment: @m1crdy No, you can't. If I understand you correctly you want the entire `<element1></element1>` tag. Regular expressions are not enough to catch it in general.

Comment: @Bergi I neet to develop a application that generate erorrs in XML-documents for my final exam

Comment: @m1crdy Then just insert few `<` at random.

Comment: the editor.find statement always finds the first element. But it should be random. is there a way with javascript to call this statement in random order? 1-2 or 3 times eg?

Comment: @m1crdy: But why do you need to do that in an editor? Regex alone is not capable of this btw, tell us more about your environment. Can't you use `Math.random()` and select an arbitrary range?

Comment: go to xml.lmenges.de then paste some xml code. then click "überprüfen". if the code is valid plz click "fehler einbauen". then click some times till you see the marker in the code editor moving and selecting some elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find all ranges and pick one of them randomly

```
editor.$search.setOptions({needle: "<[a-z]+", regExp:true, preventScroll: true});
ranges = editor.$search.findAll(editor.session)
randomRange = ranges[Math.floor(Math.random() * ranges.length)]
if (randomRange)
    editor.selection.setRange(randomRange)
```

or randomly pick starting position

```
i = Math.floor(Math.random() * editor.getValue().length)
startPos = editor.session.doc.indexToPosition(i)
editor.find("<[a-z]+",{regExp:true, start: startPos})
```

update: the second method isn't good since it's distribution isn't uniform

Comment: Ty. But the code is not working :( there is nothing selected :(

Comment: The second solution gives error: undefined is not a function in line 2

Comment: I see you even opened an issue on ace website, Fyi it's wrong to open bug reports for random questions from your homework, on all available forums. And it's even worse if your issues are poorly worded, i would never understand what you want from the issue you opened there. You should at least close that issue.

Comment: @a user Thank you for your reply. i closed that issue.